# Django render_to_string() ignores {% csrf_token %}

Tags: django

I am trying to perform unit tests in Django. I have the following form in `index.html`:

```
<form method=POST>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input name=itemT>
</form>
```

And I am testing if the view render the template correctly:

views.py

```
def homePage(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

tests.py:

```
request = HttpRequest()

response = homePage(request)
if response:
    response = response.content.decode('UTF-8')

expectedHTML = render_to_string('index.html')
self.assertEqual(response, expectedHTML)
```

The `response` has a hidden input field with a csrf token; however, the `expectedHTML` does not (there is just a blank line at the place of `{% csrf_token %}`). So the assertion always fails.

Is it possible to have `render_to_string()` generate a csrf input field? If so, would the token of `response` the same as that of `expectedHTML`?

Or, is there any way to ignore the input field such that the test can be successful?

Comment: Maybe it's not what you need, but consider changing the test. Is it the best idea to test the response by comparing whole HTML inside the template page? Maybe it's better to you `assertContains` with fields you really need to check.

Comment: Your test is just checking that `render` renders a template in the same way as `render_to_string`. That isn't really helpful, because there will already be tests in Django to make sure that `render` and `render_to_string` work. The important thing for you to test is whether the view is rendering the correct template (you could use [`assertTemplateUsed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertTemplateUsed)), or check for specific content in the response (use `assertContains`).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To get the csrf token to work when using [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string), you need to supply the `request` object so that the context processors run.

In Django 1.8+, you can simply pass the request as an argument

```
return render_to_string('index.html', request=request)
```

On earlier versions, you can use a `RequestContext`.

```
from django.template import RequestContext
render_to_string('index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: ``context_instance`` is [deprecated since Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) for ``render_to_string``. Use ``render_to_string('index.html', request=request)`` instead.

Comment: @LutzPrechelt - Yes, you shouldn't use `context_instance` in Django 1.8+. I had written `render` instead of `render_to_string` before. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed an issue with an older unit testing book I was working through.

Comment: This seems to help, but as https://stackoverflow.com/a/39859042 states, the token changes per request and the test won't pass. Thanks @Alasdair for editing the gist below, I'll add it to my TDD book work-through. (I'm using Django 2.2)

Answer (score 20):

Unfortunately Alasdair’s answer won't work with `Django 1.10` as the `csrf_token` changes on each request. Please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/horvatha/2e11b48f431c53b101db6cb817b2fc7f) that works on 1.10. (Altered the code a bit to fix the typo from the original gist)

```
class HomePageTest(TestCase):

    @staticmethod
    def remove_csrf(html_code):
        csrf_regex = r'<input[^>]+csrfmiddlewaretoken[^>]+>'
        return re.sub(csrf_regex, '', html_code)

    def assertEqualExceptCSRF(self, html_code1, html_code2):
        return self.assertEqual(
            self.remove_csrf(html_code1),
            self.remove_csrf(html_code2)
        )
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add an argument like this.

```
render_to_string('index.html', request=request)
```

Please refer to the [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string).

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 2, you can do this:

```
html = render_to_string('my_template.html', context, request=request)
```